# Possible to drop the original query parameters entirely in a rewritten URL?

Tags: htaccess, url-rewriting, permalinks

Original URL looks something like `domain.com/filename.php?id1=333&id2=444`.

Desired rewritten URL is something like `domain.com/my-rewritten-url`.

I can imagine creating a lookup table with columns for the ids and a column for the rewrite string, but is this realistic/practical?

Comment: This is exactly how Drupal.org functions, their URL Alias transforms the default query string (example.com?q=/path/to/page) to a "normal" URI path (example.com/path/to/page). The main thing is an Apache2 rewrite that changes the simple /path/to/page to index.php?q=/path/to/page. Then the index.php script handles the request by finding the page (via a set of menu rules). I wrote about this on this page http://snapwebsites.org/implementation/basic-concept-url-website in a rather extensive way...

Comment: Hi, in my case however I only have numbers as the original URL and I want an associated piece of data, a string (a separate column found in the same database table)

Comment: I guess the one problem you could run into is a bit of slowness, but numbers or strings it can work just fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is very possible to implement.  I have implemented it myself.  It requires more than a rewrite rule though.  It requires you to change the code that runs your web application.  Here is how I have made it work:

- A request comes in for `/my-rewritten-url`
- A rewrite rule forwards it to `/filename.php?path=my-rewritten-url
- The PHP script does a database query to get the parameter string (`id1=333&id2=444`) and the file name that should handle the request (`show-this-page-type.php`)
- It parses that parameter string and puts the values into the parameter map
- It dispatches the request to `show-this-page-type.php`

The downsides are:

- It adds an extra database query (caching can help)
- It requires that your website be powered by a single script that may have to dispatch requests out to other scripts
- It breaks analytics that are rely on the existence of parameters in the URLs or the name of the script.  (It is much harder to determine page type, for example.)

Comment: Hi, thank you – this is very helpful and will assist in determining the ROI of this activity :)